# Using &nbsp; within OGNL is being displayed as &nbsp; and not a space

Tags: struts2, html-entities, ognl

I have the following nested struts 2 tags in a jsp.  This is within another iterator which is in turn inside a td tag for an html table.

```
<s:property value="#rule.value" />
<s:set var="blanks" value="''" />
<s:iterator value="(#rule.key.length()).{ #this }">
   <s:set var="blanks" value="%{#blanks + '&nbsp;'}" />
</s:iterator>
<s:property value="#blanks" />
```

The overall goal is to render all s:property values you see on the same line in the browser.  For some tags (like textfield) you can change the theme attribute and it does not try to print everything on its own line.  But anyhow, I need everything on the same line within an iterator tag.

So what I am trying to do here is to build up a string of nbsp.  The length of such a string will change each time this code snippet is iterated over.  When I run this, the iterator executes the correct number of times, but my output is `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`..... as many times as the loop is iterated.  I need an html space output for each nbsp though.  Ultimately, I need the td to have a certain amount of characters in it so that this table and a separate table sync up as far as screen formatting goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `escapeHtml`.

```
<s:property value="#blanks" escapeHtml="false" />
```

**or just**

```
${blanks}
```

---

`escapeHtml` / `escape` (Deprecated) **:** default is `true`

Comment: Spent so much time looking at the set tag and OGNL, that I neglected looking at the output tag, property. But it is right there at http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/property.html: escape/escapeHtml is an attribute of property. Good job, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a whole lot about JSP tags, but I come across them every now and again... Have you ever seen `escapeXml="false"`? (used in the c:out tag)

Comment: I will look in that direction. Of course EL expressions cannot occur within struts 2 tags (that would be THE solution if they could) but I will look for the equivalent sort of thing in OGNL.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `&nbsp;`  instead of `&nbsp` for easy formatting and giving spaces anywhere you want , in struts framework too,and avoiding too much complexities.